# Combining contents of files by reading them in a human ordering

Tags: java, io, lambda

This code review is inspired by the [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411299/sort-files-in-numeric-order) and written in Java 8.

The code is supposed to:

1. Order all files, with syntax `jobXXX.script`, where `XXX` is a number, by the number.
2. Write the contents of the files in that ordering to one file.

I am asking for a general code review and there are two things that are bugging me:

- I need to wrap `Exception`s inside lambda expressions.
- The file that is being written to, has an imperfect unnecessary annoying OCD-triggering newline at the end.

---

```
package testproject4;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 *
 * @author Beheerder
 */
public class TestProject4 {
    private void init() throws IOException {
        Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\testjob");
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(directory.resolve("masterjob.script"))) {
            Files.list(directory)
                    .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
                    .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().matches("job\\d+.script"))
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::pathToInt))
                    .flatMap(this::wrappedLines)
                    .forEach(string -> wrappedWrite(writer, string));
        }
    }

    private int pathToInt(final Path path) {
        return Integer.parseInt(path.getFileName()
                .toString()
                .replaceAll("job(\\d+).script", "$1")
        );
    }

    private Stream<String> wrappedLines(final Path path) {
        try {
            return Files.lines(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //swallow
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void wrappedWrite(final BufferedWriter writer, final String string) {
        try {
            writer.write(string);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //swallow
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new TestProject4().init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NewLine

The newline at the end is correct... at least according to your code.

`Files.lines(...)` ignores the last line of input files if it has no characters. This is a standard system to have for most operating systems (the last character in a text file is a newline).

Your code is perpetuating this process, and it always adds a newline after each line printed.

Thus, your file always ends up with a newline at the end. This is a good thing.

### Exceptions

Java Lambdas cannot contain expressions that throw caught exceptions. This is a weakness. The weakness is so sever that as part of Java8, there is the new Exception [`UncheckedIOException`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) so that IO-based operations can throw an unchecked exception.

The easiest way to use it is to change your catch blocks to:

```
private Stream<String> wrappedLines(final Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(path);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}
```

The alternative is to wrap the exception inside the lambda with:

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(directory.resolve("masterjob.script"))) {
        Files.list(directory)
                .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().matches("job\\d+.script"))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(this::pathToInt))
                .flatMap(try { this::wrappedLines } catch(IOException ioe) {throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe)})
                .forEach(string -> try {wrappedWrite(writer, string)} catch(IOException ioe) {throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe)});
    }
```

### General

The Java8 side of this otherwise looks OK, and works fine for me too.